# LDAP Queries in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ldap-query

Has anyone any experience of querying LDAP in C# and fields coming back with no value?

I have some attributes in LDAP that I know are populated but these do not come through when querying in a C# app. Some fields do, some don't.

Any help/advice much appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the main code:

```
string adResults = string.Empty;
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP, USER, PASSWORD);
directorySearcher.Filter = "(mail=" = EmailAddress + ")";

directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");

SearchResult res = directorySearcher.FindOne();
adResults += (String)res.Properties["cn"][0];
adResults += (String)res.Properties["company"][0];

return adResults;
```

Comment: post your code to get help.  This is to open-ended to  answer.

Comment: Code added to main post. Basically, I want to bring back the cn and company for the email address entered. cn returns data, but company doesn't. However, looking at AD, both fields have data.

Comment: Your code runs fine and returns the correct results when I tested it.  Maybe the issue is with your LDAP string so something like `LDAP://YourDomain.com/OU=Domain Users,DC=YourDomainName,DC=com`

Comment: Hi Sorceri,

My LDAP String does look like that - I've just got it stored in a separate variable. 

Thanks :)

Comment: FYI `"(mail=" = EmailAddress + ")";` should be `"(mail=" + EmailAddress + ")";`  Anyway...it is probably a permissions issue then.

Comment: Permissions issue, even though some information does come back??